# How to redirect to another page in codeigniter from one page?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have written a code in the controller which is given below. This code is for login page. In this code, the if statement notification is properly working but the else part is not working. It is not redirect to the url given in the redirect() instead it is showing a blank page. Can anyone tell y it is like that and correct it for me ? I have used header() function but also it is not working.I have placed all the code inside the 'kw' folder. This code is properly working in the localhost but when uploaded the same code to the live server, its not working.Is it due to version of the CI ?

```
<?php
     if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
     exit('No direct script access allowed');
     class Login extends CI_Controller {
          public function __construct() {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->library('session');
                $this->load->library('validation');

                $this->load->model('studentsmodel');
     }
     public function index() {
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
            {
               $post_data = array('stud_cin' => $this->input->post('stud_cin'),'stud_password' => $this->input->post('stud_password'), 
                            );


               $this->validation->set_data($post_data);
               $this->validation->set_rules('stud_cin','Cin','required|trim');
               $this->validation->set_rules('stud_password','Password','required|trim');
               if ($this->validation->run() === FALSE) 
               {

               } 
               else 
               {
                $this->load->model("studentsmodel");
                $this->load->helper('url');
                $result = $this->studentsmodel->loginCheck($post_data); 
                if (!$result){
                    $this->notifications->notify('Wrong username/password; Login Failed','error');

                }
                else{

                         $this->session->set_userdata('student_id', $result['id']);
                         $this->session->set_userdata('stud_cin', $result['stud_cin']);
                         $this->session->set_userdata('stud_photopath', $result['stud_photopath']);


                        redirect('student/profile/edit/id/'.$this->session->userdata('student_id'),'refresh');

                         //header('location:http://www.website.com/kw/application/controller/student/profile/edit/id/$this->session->userdata("student_id")');
                }

        }
    }        $this->load->view("login");
}
}
```

profile controller edit function

```
 public function index()
 {

    $student_id=$this->session->userdata('student_id');
     $data['profile_data'] =$this->studentsmodel->get_Cinprofile($student_id);

     $this->load->view("profileDetails.php", $data);
}


public function edit() 
{   
$uri = $this->uri->uri_to_assoc(4);
$student_id=$uri['id'];
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit']))
{

   //echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES);exit;

  $img_val      = $this->studentsmodel->getStudent_photo($student_id);
  $photo_val    = $img_val['stud_photopath'];
  $photo_unlink = "";


  if ($_FILES['stud_photopath']['name'] != "") 
  {
      /*echo "in";exit;*/
     $photo_chk    = explode("photo/", $photo_val);
     $photo_unlink = $photo_chk[1];
     $photo_path = "";
     $flag       = "";
     $f_type_chk = $_FILES['stud_photopath']['type'];

     if ($f_type_chk != "image/gif" && $f_type_chk != "image/jpg" && $f_type_chk != "image/jpeg"
          && $f_type_chk != "image/bmp" && $f_type_chk != "image/png" && $f_type_chk != "") 
     {
          $flag = "Select allowed file type and size for photo";
     }
     if ($_FILES['stud_photopath']['size'] >= 5242880) {  $flag = "Select allowed file type and size for photo";  }

      $target_path = getcwd() . "/public/photo/";
      $db_path     = "photo/";

     if ($_FILES['stud_photopath']['name'] != '')
     {
          $file_name     = $_FILES["stud_photopath"]["name"];
          $file_size     = $_FILES["stud_photopath"]["size"] / 1024;
          $file_type     = $_FILES["stud_photopath"]["type"];
          $file_tmp_name = $_FILES["stud_photopath"]["tmp_name"];
          $random        = rand(111, 999);
          $new_file_name = $random . $file_name;
          $newfile_name=$cin."_". $file_name;

          $upload_path   = $target_path . $newfile_name;;

         if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $upload_path))  { $photo_path = addslashes($db_path . $newfile_name);  } /*end if*/

        else { $this->notifications->notify('Photo cannot upload', 'error');  }/*end else var_dump($this->validation->show_errors());*/
      }/*end if $_FILES['photo']['name']*/

     } /*END OF  if ($_FILES['photo']['name'] != "") */

  else  {   $photo_path = $photo_val; } /*END OF   ELSE ($_FILES['photo']['name'] != "") */



         $this->session->unset_userdata('stud_photopath');
         $this->session->set_userdata('stud_photopath', $photo_path);

         $data['photo_unlink'] = $photo_unlink;
        /* echo $dob_dd = $this->input->post('dob_dd');exit;
         $dob_mm =  $this->input->post('dob_mm');
         $dob_yy = $this->input->post('dob_yy');
         $dob       = $dob_dd . "-" . $dob_mm . "-" . $dob_yy;*/
         $stud_age_dob  =$this->input->post('stud_age_dob');
         $timestamp = strtotime($stud_age_dob);
         $dob      = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);


         $validation_data  = array(
                              'stud_name'   => $this->input->post('stud_name'),
                              'stud_gender'    => $this->input->post('stud_gender'),
                              'stud_age_dob'  =>$this->input->post('stud_age_dob'),
                              'stud_mobile' => $this->input->post('stud_mobile'),
                              'stud_email' => $this->input->post('stud_email'),
                           );  
                      //echo "<pre>";print_r($validation_data); exit;          
                        $this->validation->set_data($validation_data);
                        $this->validation->set_rules('stud_name', 'Student Name', 'trim|alpha_space|required');
                        $this->validation->set_rules('stud_gender', 'Gender', 'required');
                        $this->validation->set_rules('stud_age_dob', 'DOB', 'required');

                        $this->validation->set_rules('stud_mobile', 'Mobile number', 'numeric|required');
                        $this->validation->set_rules('stud_email', 'Email Id', 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean');


                        if ($this->validation->run() === FALSE) 
                        { /* var_dump($this->validation->show_errors()); */ $this->notifications->notify('Please make all entries', 'error');} 
                        else 
                        {

                            $updation_data=array(

                                                  'stud_name'   => $this->input->post('stud_name'),
                                                  'stud_gender'   => $this->input->post('stud_gender'),
                                                  'stud_age_dob'    => $this->input->post('stud_age_dob'),
                                                  'stud_gaurdian'  =>$this->input->post('stud_gaurdian'),
                                                  'stud_mother'  =>$this->input->post('stud_mother'),
                                                  'stud_mobile'        => $this->input->post('stud_mobile'),
                                                  'stud_email'  => $this->input->post('stud_email'),
                                                  'stud_tel'  => $this->input->post('stud_tel'),
                                                  'stud_guardian_address' => $this->input->post('stud_guardian_address'),

                                                  'stud_pin' => $this->input->post('stud_pin'),
                                                  'stud_photopath' => $photo_path,
                                                  'stud_age_dob'   => $dob
                                                 );

                            /*echo "<pre>";print_r($updation_data); exit;   */           
                            $update_status=$this->studentsmodel->update_profile($updation_data, $student_id);

                            if($update_status==1)
                              {
                                  //$this->session->set_userdata('profile_status', 'Yes');
                                  /*$this->session->userdata('profile_status');*/
                                  redirect('student/profile/index/', 'refresh');
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                  $this->notifications->notify('profile updted failed', 'error');


                              }
                              $data['profile_data']=$_POST;




                        }
      $data['profile_data']=$_POST;
  }


   $data['profile_data']=$this->studentsmodel->get_Cinprofile($student_id);
   $this->load->view("profile_edit.php",$data);
}
```

Comment: what is your `controller` name and what is that `id` in your redirect function

Comment: hope you have set your base url in config.php? use redirect with base_url i

Comment: controller name is Login and 'id' is just a label.

Comment: ya..I have tried that but it is not working

Comment: is `student` is your directory name?

Comment: how to write the redirect code with base_url ?

Comment: ya..it is the folder name @ Yadhu

Comment: You might need to set some routes https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: Its not the problm of routing.. The redirect() inside the if statement is not working.

Comment: make sure you have given correct address and folder name. Server's are case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if you already load this helper

   `$this->load->helper('url');`
2. This is the information about the redirect function

   `redirect($uri = '', $method = 'auto', $code = NULL);`

Parameters:

1. $uri (string) URI string  $method (string)
2. Redirect method (‘auto’,
   ‘location’ or ‘refresh’)
3. $code (string) HTTP Response code (usually 302 or 303)

*Note:*

Don't forget add in the config file the value for `base_uri`

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/config.html

Answer (score 0):

remove `/id/` from your `redirect()`

```
redirect('student/profile/edit/'.$this->session->userdata('student_id'));
```